# How do I get a JWT from a Cognito Hosted UI code resp

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm using amazon-cognito for authentication. I'm trying to move to using the hosted UI. The hosted UI redirects to my url hosted with node.js:

https://myapp.com/auth-code?code=abcd-abcd

How do I take that code string and turn it into an id jwt token that could be verified with the following code?

```
import { CognitoJwtVerifier } from "aws-jwt-verify";


const verifier = CognitoJwtVerifier.create({
  userPoolId: "user pool id",
  tokenUse: null,
  clientId: "client id",
});
const cognitoPayload = await verifier.verify(
  cognitoJWT // the JWT as string
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're following the oauth authorization code grant flow, so what you need to do is send the code off to the Cognito service's token endpoint which will allow you to exchange the code for a token. It looks like the Amazon Cognito endpoint is [documented here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html)

The full flow is like this:

User takes some login action --> User is redirected to hosted login or IdP login where they enter their credentials --> The service returns a code to your NodeJS server --> Your NodeJS server makes a new HTTP request forwarding the code in the format below to the Cognito service's /oauth2/token endpoint --> The token endpoint responds to the specified redirect uri (also on your NodeJS server) with the token.

Here's a snippet of code doing exactly what you're trying to do:

```js
function exchangeCode(code, gatewayUrl) {
            const params = {"code": code,
                "grant_type": "authorization_code",
                "redirect_uri": getRedirectURI(gatewayUrl)};
            const headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Authorization": getBase64EncodedCredential()};
            const options = {
                hostname: getCognitoHost(true),
                port: 443,
                path: "/oauth2/token",
                method: 'POST',
                headers: headers
            };
```

I pulled the above code [from here.](https://github.com/JinlianWang/aws-lambda-authentication-nodejs/blob/master/src/handlers/authentication-service.js)

Comment: Here's another quick article covering your use case. One more HTTP call and you're home free:
https://www.yippeecode.com/topics/aws-cognito-oauth-2-authorization-code-flow/